# Error while launching uboost.py from PHP script

Tags: php, python

I get this error while launching the uboost.py from a PHP script

> Unable to create process using
>   'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37
>   python.exe "C:\uboost\uboost.py" arg1 arg2 ; echo Exit status : $?'

I'm running it from this script:

```
<?php
function liveExecuteCommand($cmd)
{

    while (@ ob_end_flush()); // end all output buffers if any

    $proc = popen("$cmd 2>&1 ; echo Exit status : $?", 'r');

    $live_output     = "";
    $complete_output = "";

    while (!feof($proc))
    {
        $live_output     = fread($proc, 4096);
        $complete_output = $complete_output . $live_output;
        echo "$live_output";
        @ flush();
    }

    pclose($proc);

    // get exit status
    preg_match('/[0-9]+$/', $complete_output, $matches);

    // return exit status and intended output
    return array (
                    'exit_status'  => intval($matches[0]),
                    'output'       => str_replace("Exit status : " . $matches[0], '', $complete_output)
                 );
}
    //$output = shell_exec('python C:/uboost/uboost.py pignalice Cazzo1234');
    liveExecuteCommand("python C:/uboost/uboost.py pignalice Cazzo1234");
?>
```

Hope that someone knows the reason
Thanks

Comment: This error doesn't match up with the code shown. Details on paths and actually present binaries are missing. And Windows´ CMD doesn't support shell idions like `;` or `$?`. Look for the real error code.

Comment: PD of [How can I debug exec() problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/12199353)